# Show that there is an $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(A-rI_d)^2 (z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Show that there is an $r\in \mathbb{R} $ and a $z\in \mathbb{R} ^{3} $ such that $\left( A-rI_{d}  \right) ^{2} \left( z \right) =\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ but $\left( A-rI_{d}  \right)z \neq \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Where $$A = \left[\begin{array}{l}
 3&-2&2 \\
 4&-4&6 \\
 2&-3&5 
\end{array}\right]$$
Matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda=1,2$ and eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I tried using the eigenvalues a $r$ and the eigenvalues as $z$ but I still can't get it right.

Comment: This is just the eigenvalue equation - can you prove the matrix has an eigenvalue and an eigenvector?

Comment: Yes, I have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I will be updating the post. Also could you elaborate on what the eigenvalue equation is?

Comment: $r$ is either 1 or 2. You just need to see if you can find solutions to $(A-rI)z=v_r$ for one of those two eigenvectors. You could figure out which by seeing which eigenvalue has multiplicity 2 in the characteristic equation.